# Use alias with URL for import.meta.url

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack

I have two modules: `client` and `processor`.

- The `client` module is for the web browser window this contains a module that can be used in the browser window.
- The `processor` module is a web worker that contains the code to do web worker work.

In my client I trigger the web worker like this:

```js
export class WebWorker {
  constructor() {
    const url = new URL('../../processor/src/worker.ts', import.meta.url);
    this.worker = new Worker(url);
  }
}
```

Is there a way for me to load the URL string using an import/alias so I would do something like this:

```js
const url = new URL('@org/processor/worker.ts', import.meta.url);
```

I would like to do this so I can decouple the two modules, currently as it is, if it cannot find the url it throws an error.

I have something similar in my package.json

```json
{
  "dependencies": {
    "@org/processor": "file:./path/to/processor",
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi. Did you find a solution?

Comment: No I did not find a solution.